# Move only 2 item in jquery ui-sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to use jquery ui-sortable to moving element. this plugin moving element like this :
1 , 2 , 3 , 4   and if I move the 4 to the 1 place. It will be  4 , 1 , 2 , 3

In my case, I want to move only 2 item, example :
1 , 2 , 3 , 4 and if I move 4 to the 1 place, I want it move like this : 4, 2 , 3 , 1

Any one can help me? Or any suggestions for this one?

Comment: You can do this by specifying the `items` in a sense. What code have you tried or what code are you using currently?

Comment: i'm using jquery sortable default code for grid style `$( "#sortable" ).sortable();` and using the example css for the grid view in this website `https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid`

Comment: Then you may want to review https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#items too.